# Delete Derived Class with Stack Pointer?

Tags: c++, memory, derived-class

So stack memory cannot be manually be freed up via delete, because this somehow induces UB. But when creating a derived class object, the "new"-keyword is involved. Say for example:

```
void some_function(){
    Base* base;
    base = new Derived;
}
```

As "new" is involved, is base = new Derived now located on the heap? And if so, does the memory where it is located, need to be freed up manually again? Or is it located on the stack and the memory will be freed up after the program terminates anyway?

Comment: 1) The allocated memory is in heap.
2) It should be manually deleted. Better approach is to use smart pointers like `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`.
3) When the program terminates the memory is freed up. But you keep on allocating memory and not deleting it will leak memory.

Answer (score 4):

The rule is: *Any time you use `new`, you must free the memory with `delete`.* The only exception is for something called "placement `new`" which is rarely used (see comments).

In your case, the *pointer* called `base` is itself located on the stack. However, what it points to is allocated on the heap.

When your program terminates, *all* of its memory will be freed by the kernel. It doesn't matter where or how the memory was allocated.

<sub>(Note to pedants: I am using "stack" and "heap" here as per common usage, notwithstanding the fact that those terms are not mentioned in the C++ standard.)</sub>

Comment: There are no exceptions, except for placement `new`.  After placement `new`, one should clean up using an explicit destructor call, not `delete`.

Comment: Wait. ALL will be freed up? I thought allocated heap memory would stay allocated until the system reboots if it isn't freed up.

Comment: @lotolmencre: No. All heap memory allocated by your program will be freed when your program terminates. Of course, if your program doesn't terminate (for example, if it is something like a network server that is designed to run for a long time), then that memory stays allocated while your program is active.

Comment: That means, if I need all the instances for as long as the program runs anyway, I don't need to actually go through the hassle to delete them all again? That sound like sloppy practice though.

Comment: @lotolmencre: That is correct. Whether that is "sloppy" or not depends on your point of view.

Answer (score 4):

When dealing with pointers, don't confuse the memory the pointer takes with the memory the pointer is pointing at.

In your function, `base` is a function local variable, and it will be cleaned up when it goes out of scope. However, the memory `base` points at will not.

```
Before allocation: 
--------
| base |
--------
freed at end of scope

After allocation:
--------                    ---------------
| base | ===============>   | new Derived |
--------                    ---------------
freed at end of scope       Will not be freed
```

However, if you add in `delete base;` to your function:

```
--------                    ---------------
| base | ===============>   | new Derived |
--------                    ---------------
freed at end of function    freed by "delete base;"
```